# Cannot link EGL

Tags: libraries, opengl, symbolic-link

I have installed the latest NVIDIA drivers and tried to link `EGL` library, but somehow it does not work.

```
g++ -o hello hello.cpp -lEGL

hello.cpp:2:23: fatal error: EGL/egl.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

Here you can see that the EGL.so is in `/usr/lib`

```
ldconfig -p | grep EGL
    libEGL_nvidia.so.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/nvidia-384/libEGL_nvidia.so.0
    libEGL_nvidia.so.0 (libc6) => /usr/lib32/nvidia-384/libEGL_nvidia.so.0
    libEGL.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/nvidia-384/libEGL.so.1
    libEGL.so.1 (libc6) => /usr/lib32/nvidia-384/libEGL.so.1
    libEGL.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/nvidia-384/libEGL.so
    libEGL.so (libc6) => /usr/lib32/nvidia-384/libEGL.so

nvidia-smi

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 384.130                Driver Version: 384.130                   |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  Tesla K80           On   | 00000000:00:1E.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   34C    P8    28W / 149W |      1MiB / 11439MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|  No running processes found                                                 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: That error appears to be from the compile phase - not the link phase

Comment: Well the EGL library is not linked therefore it cannot be fonud. @steeldriver

Comment: Header files are not libraries

Comment: Yeah, how do I include the path of the "EGL.h" directory then? @steeldriver

Comment: Do the NVIDIA proprietary drivers even install development headers? if not, you may need to install the native Ubuntu `libegl1-mesa-dev` package

Comment: Okay, yeah that is what I always did, but then I thought this will harm my GPU performance? So I guess there is no other way? @steeldriver

Comment: Would you mind having a look at this  [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50775187/headless-rendering-amazon-aws-ec2-plarge-using-opengl-egl) This is very related, but I just cannot figure it out @steeldriver

Comment: Perhaps you need CUDA?

Comment: CUDA is installed @steeldriver